# using pandas to count sentences and words inside a csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, word-count

I'm trying to create a python program that goes through a csv file that the user chooses, and prints total number of sentences, based on a full stop or new line, and total number of all words.

**insert the file**

**total number of sentences is :3**

**total number of words: 15**

**total number of words wothout repetation is: 12**

```
data = pd.read_csv('dundun.csv', sep='\t')
words = data['sentences'].str.split(expand=True)
word_count = {}
for word in words:
    count = word_count.get(word, 0)
    count += 1
    word_count[word] = count
print(word_count)
```

I'm trying this code but it gives me wrong output for counting words
my csv looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
import string
nwords = data['sentences'].str.split().map(len).sum()
nsenetences = data['sentences'].count()
nunique_words = len(set([x for i in data['senetences'].str.split().apply(lambda x: [''.join([y for y in i if y not in string.punctuation]) for i in x]).tolist() for x in i]))
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205576/discussion-between-programming-freak-and-u10-forward-reinstate-monica).

Answer (score 3):

For dataframe df, count sentences:

```
df['review_sentence_count'] = df['reviews'].apply(sent_tokenize).tolist()
df['review_sentence_count'] = df['review_sentence_count'].apply(len)
```

Count words after removing punctuations:

```
string_text = df['reviews'].str
df['reviews'] = string_text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
df['review_word_count'] = df['reviews'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist()
df['review_word_count'] = df['review_word_count'].apply(len)
```

Write new data with new columns to a csv:

```
df.to_csv('./data/dataset.csv')
```